# Termux (specifically npm) can't install in internal storage

Tags: file-permissions, termux

Everytime I try to use NPM to install something into /storage/emulated/0/dir it would always do this:

```
npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, futime
npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, futime
npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, futime
npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, futime
npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, futime
npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, futime
npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, futime
npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, futime
npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, futime
npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, futime
npm WARN tar EPERM: operation not permitted, futime
```

It has access to download things using git and other methods but it never seems to work using NPM.

Comment: When installing something with npm try the `--user` option: `npm install --user`

Comment: Probably it would work with a `HOME=/data/data/com.termux/files npm -i ...`, does it?